# Model does not contain a definition for 'input'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to take what a user inputs in a textbox from the view and add it to a String in the model.  Errors I am getting are: 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'input'

and

no extension method 'input' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Inside my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Summary", "inquire", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.input)
```

Model:

```
namespace myProj.Models
{
public class myModel
{
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string input { get; set;}
  ..
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Summary(String input)
    {
        ..

        if (Request.HttpMethod.ToLower().Equals("get"))
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ..

            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

Issue I am having in the view with the TextBoxFor line in my view, if I put @model myProj.Models.myModel at the top I can get it to work, however I need to use @model IEnumerable when I want to use foreach and display the data I get from this input to a table.

I feel it's something simple I am missing, but i fail to see it.

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<myProj.Models.myModel>` would solve one problem.  Your model looks like the property should be called `inputFeinID`.

Comment: That was a typo when i added it here, input is it's name.  Thank you for pointing that out.

I am using @model IEnumerable<myProj.Models.myModel>, that's what causing my m => m.input to give an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use multiple instances of your model, you're going to have to iterate them in your view, something like this:

```
@model List<myProj.Models.myModel>
```

Then do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].input)
}
```

We'll need to change your `ActionResult` to handle multiple models though

**Note, you don't have to check the request type if it's a `HttpGet`, let's split it out into two methods**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Summary()
{
    return View(new List<myProj.Models.myModel>());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Summary(List<myProj.Models.myModel> input)
{
    return View(input);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I already have @model IEnumberable<myProj.Models.myModel>. 

When I do the for loop, i get an error at the index saying "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable".

And yes thank you for pointing out the two methods, was my future plan but I want to get the main functionality down before making it cleaner.

Comment: Change the model to `IList<myProj.Models.myModel>` instead of `IEnumerable<myProj.Models.myModel>` so you can use the `for` loop (or use an `EditorTemplate` if it must be `IEnumerable`) and don't use `input` as the parameter name in the POST method (its already the name of a model property so binding will fail) - use something like `public ActionResult Summary(IEnumerable<myProj.Models.myModel> model)`

Comment: @mattytommo thank you, that fixed the original issue I was having, however now when I put the textboxfor inside the for loop, it doesn't appear on the webpage when I run it, assuming the model.count never gets above 0?

Comment: @StephenMuecke input is just the name I used to ask the question, I do have a better, more meaningful name in my actual code, thank you for your response.

Comment: @vandrj63 No problems, if you're not populating anything in your `HttpGet` method, then yeah count will always be 0. If you want to add some records, add them in your `HttpGet` method. If you tell me how many you want in there I can update my answer to show you how.

Comment: @mattytommo I guess I should have explained more in my original post. The page comes up with just the textbox and button to submit the string.  After the button click a table appears on the page with information retrieved from the database based on that input (ID number).  
So i guess answer to your question of how many, would be none until user submits the input.